# Why is yum's tab completion slow?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, package-management, yum

Why is yum's tab completion slow? Is it because it needs to connect to the internet? If yes, how can I disable that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's going over the internet to run the partial commands when you hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. The tab completion has nothing really to do with Yum. It's a function of the shell, Bash, in this case.

You can see the commands that are configured to provide tab completion using the `complete` command:

```
$ complete | grep yum
complete -o filenames -F _yum yum
complete -o filenames -F _yu_yumdb yumdb
complete -o filenames -F _yu_yumdb yumdb.py
complete -o filenames -F _yum yummain.py
```

You can disable the use of tab completion for Yum by moving/removing the file in this directory, `/etc/etc/bash_completion.d/yum.bash`.

If removing the file seems heavy handed, which it is, you can also disable completion all together by adding this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
$ complete -r
```

You can also remove it for single apps like this:

```
$ complete -r yum
```

Or a group of them:

```
$ complete -r yum perl
```

You can get a list of what apps are configured to use completion using this command:

```
$ complete -p
```

#### References

- [Disable bash autocompletion on Ubuntu](http://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/06/19/disable-bash-autocompletion-on-ubunt/)

Comment: thanks, could you please help me how to disable connecting to internet and searching in local indexes?

Comment: @slm you are a machine bro :D

Comment: @slm Thanks But I want to keep completion work for yum, although without connecting to the internet. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Farzam `/etc/init.d/network stop`, do your `yum` stuff, `/etc/init.d/network start`... probably not what you want though ;)

Comment: @Farzam - understand. Looking in the `yum.bash` file it looks like it should only be hitting the cache: `$( ${yum:-yum} -d 0 -C list $1 "$2*" 2>/dev/null | \ `. The `-C` switch is suppose to do that. You can confirm the performance by doing that line yourself in a shell. `yum -d 0 -C list all "somepkg*"`.

Comment: I'd guess much of the slowness is in that implementation. A `yum list all ...` is pretty inefficient way to do that.

Comment: @slm is that yum-utils.bash or yum.bash? I cannot find yum.bash there. and which line should I change? I cannot find something like what you wrote there.

Comment: @Farzam - yum.bash. That file was installed as part of yum. `rpm -qf /etc/bash_completion.d/yum.bash` = `yum-3.2.28-7.fc14.noarch`. List the contents of your yum to see if it hsa something similar: `rpm -ql yum`.